# How to have exception for some words - Regex in django url pattern?

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

In my website, people can visit other's profile with url like `https://example.com/slug-profile`, here is the pattern:

```
path('<slug:slug>',views.profile,name='profile')
```

I also want that users go to `settings`,`notifications`:

```
path('settings',views.param,name='param')
# https://example.com/settings

path('notifications',views.notifications,name='notifications')
# https://example.com/notifications
```

But in this case, `settings` will be considered as a slug. I have already set a function to avoid users to have `slug` like `settings` or `notifications`.

I see that some websites use a prefix or something similar

```
www.example.com/user/settings/
```

```
www.twitter.com/i/notifications/
```

In my project I would do:

```
re_path(r'^(?P<slug>\w{5,})$',views.profile,name='profile')

path('i/settings',views.param,name='param')
```

`i` or `user` will never be considered as a `slug` profile since the slug regex expression must have at least 5 characters.

How to have thees words or a list of words `['settings','notifications']` as exceptions in a regex pattern?

Or

Do I need to go with example that contains `i` `user` in url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simpler than this. Just put your specific URLs *first*; since patterns are always matched in order, settings and notifications will match their own paths and not the slug path.